# Missing website source code when using htmlParse() in R

Tags: r, html-parsing

I'm trying to download the full source code for the following website:
http://www.carnegiehall.org/Students/.

The information I want to extract is the following section:

> Carnegie Hall Presents
>
> Thursday, March 28, 2013 | 7:30 PM
>
> Lawrence Brownlee
>
> Martin Katz
>
> Zankel Hall

View Source shows the following chunk of code for that text:

```
 <div class="info-col">
     <div class="up-lic">Carnegie Hall Presents</div>
     <div class="date">Thursday, March 28, 2013 | 7:30 PM</div> 
     <div class="clearfix"></div>
     <div class="title color">
         <a href="/Calendar/2013/3/28/0730/PM/Lawrence-Brownlee-Martin-Katz/">Lawrence Brownlee<BR>Martin Katz</a>
     </div>
     <div class="clearfix"></div>
     <div class="location"> Zankel Hall</div>
     <div class="clearfix"></div> 
     <br />
```

which is missing when I run the following in R:

```
htmlParse(getURL("http://www.carnegiehall.org/Students", .opts = curlOptions(followlocation=TRUE)), asText = TRUE)
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue is just with getting the URL (as opposed to parsing it).   The info you are looking for is not coming over, as shown here:

```
H <- getURL("http://www.carnegiehall.org/Students", .opts = curlOptions(followlocation=TRUE))

grepl("Zankel Hall", H)
# [1] FALSE

grepl("March 28", H)
# [1] FALSE
```

---

If you look closely at the html, it appears the calendar is being loaded in via script

Answer (score 0):

```
library(XML)
hdata <- htmlParse('http://www.carnegiehall.org/Students/')
xpathSApply(hdata,'//div[@class="info-col"]/div/text()|//div[@class="info-col"]/div/a/text()')
#[[1]]
#Carnegie Hall Presents 

#[[2]]
#Thursday, March 28, 2013 | 7:30 PM 

#[[3]]


#[[4]]
#Lawrence Brownlee 

#[[5]]
#Martin Katz 

#[[6]]
# Zankel Hall 

#[[7]]
```